# SELECT a subset (n=1) of records that have the same class in a category column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

For the past few days I have been stack with how to execute a query. I want to select from a table like the one below the records in which the category first changes its status.

```
Id    Category   Month

1      Start      Jan
2      Start      Feb
3      Middle     Mar
4      Middle     Apr
5      End        May
```

From that table I want only the records in which the category changed. So I want my table from the SELECT to be like that:

```
Id    Category   Month

1      Start      Jan
3      Middle     Mar
5      End        May
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: As an extra comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 3):

Pull out minimum id for every category and get the month for that record:

```
select 
  t1.id, t1.category, t2.month
from (
  select category, min(id) as id
  from yourtable
  group by category
  ) t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.category = t2.category -- second may not be necessary
```

If your `id` column is unique, then condition with `category` is not needed.
Above code would get value from `month` column for every category with minimum id.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're after can be achieved using `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT MIN(id) as ID, Category, MIN(Month) as Month
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: i think thats close but MIN(month) may not always going to be the case. perhaps. instead Min(id) for an IN clause to only pull the oldest row for category (per id assuming its auto increment)

Comment: Possibly, but given the OP's question, it sounds like it may be chronological. Given that specification, I'm not sure a more complicated query is necessary. I'll wait to see if this is the case or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes Santi that's what I wanted to do

Comment: Hello again. It seems I spoke to soon. Even though Santi's answer was very helpful there is a problem in his solution (for my table at least).                   Let me explain my new issue. The category refers to the status of a product. For most products the code works fine. Unfortunately there are products for which there is an iteration of catefories. So it might go (1)Start-(2)Middle-(3)Start-(4)Middle-(5)Middle-(6)End. I am searching for a syntax that allows me to capture all the changes thus it will return the records (1)Start-(2)Middle-(3)Start-(4)Middle-(6)End. Thank you